# What is the meaning of Face Recognition in wild and in static?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

What is meant by when someone says face recognition on wild dataset and on static dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the wild** refers to uncontrolled imagery, as opposed to images taken in lab environments or posed pictures such as driver's license/passport pictures or mug shots.

**static** in this context refers to still imagery, as opposed to temporal data (e.g. video).

With regard to facial **expression** recognition (not sure if you're interested in this related area), you could read this paper which describes a popular static database for images in the wild, which has good background information: [Static Facial Expression Analysis in Tough Conditions: Data, Evaluation Protocol and Benchmark](https://cs.anu.edu.au/few/Dhall_Goecke_Lucey_Gedeon_BEFIT_2011.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

AI models, particularly deep learning models need large amounts of training data. The performance of such models do not usually show intelligence on unseen test data. So, when we say prediction performance "**In The Wild**", it means how it performs on real-world scenario.

In computer vision, static refers to image processing. Usually, Static data does not exhibit stochastic behavior. The opposite of static is "**Dynamic**".

For more resource you can check the following videos:

[1]https://youtu.be/GCIsWeJdC9Y?t=70

[2]https://youtu.be/sIHuw8KfMa8